# Trouble Binding to a List in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, binding

I've been attempting to bind a view to a list of objects as described here [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

My problem is when the list is returned via a POST, the list contains the correct number of elements that I originally sent, but the values within the objects are coming back as if they were never set.  Not sure what I missed to make the model binder parse correctly.

Here is my test code:

My model is:

```
IList<Test>
```

where Test is defined as:

```
public class Test
{
    public int x;
}
```

In my TestController, I am using a method "Create" which has a postback:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        List<Models.Test> testList = new List<Models.Test>() {
            new Models.Test() { x = 5 }
        };

        return View(testList);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Test/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IList<Models.Test> tests)//Models.TestContainer tc)
    {
        return View(tests);
    }
```

and the "Create" view's code:

```
@model IList<ksg.Models.Test>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>TestContainer</legend>
       @Html.EditorFor(x => x[0])
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

And finally, my editor template for the Test class:

```
@model ksg.Models.Test
@using ksg.Helpers
<div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.x)
</div>
```

As shown above, I send a list with 1 item with `Test.x = 5`,  but when I breakpoint on  `Create(IList<Models.Test> tests)`, tests contains 1 object with `x = 0`.

Any ideas what I missed?

Comment: the rendered input tag looks like this: <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." name="[0].x" type="text" value="5"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and problem is that `x` in `Test` class is **field** and **not property**, thus the default model binder cannot set value from posted form. `Test` class should look like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public int X {get; set;}
}
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 5):

Try this 2 changes:

Test class:

```
      public class Test
      {
         public int x { get; set; }
      }
```

Create.cshtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>TestContainer</legend>
               @Html.EditorFor(x => x[0].x)   @*<--*@
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Yeah, the problem was not having the {get; set;} in my model.  that's what i forgot.